# How fix wierd black texture in blender?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

So I'm new to blender and I started modeling this sword by watching a Youtube tutorial. And now I don't know how to fix this issue.

[image: In Object Mode and Edit Mode]

[image]

Comment: First things to check is that there are no duplicate vertices - _Select all in edit mode > M (merge) > By Distance_. Then recalculate normals outside - _Select all > Shift+N_.

Comment: Thanks that actually worked :D